# Linking projects in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, static-libraries, static-linking

Lately I've been struggled linking libraries appropriately in C++, but it seems I have no clue how to debug these situations. Mostly I get errors for a lib file not being linked in name of unresolved external symbol, but I'm sure I linked the corresponding library.

The question actually is how to debug them. I get a referenced function, a function name where I suspect the reference is, and I get either an object file or a lib file. And then I would like to know which function is not linked (which I think I've got) and in the library list I'd like to search for the function which library it is in.

The libraries are built by me so I do have the source for them. I use windows and compile with VS2015.

Comment: Any  answer will depend on what compiler you are using and possibly the os. I mean windows, linux, solaris, bsd..

Comment: @drescherjm Right, I've added them.

Comment: dumpbin is a tool that can be used to show you the symbols in a library. `dumpbin /EXPORTS libname.lib`

Comment: @3Ducker - Are you referring to linking issues with Windows APIs, or just  linking issues in general?  The former is a bit easier, which I'm happy to write an answer for.

Comment: @drescherjm I've tried it but the lib file is rather long so the consol has overflown and given me no suitable information. May I export to a txt?

Comment: @selbie No, I have the library I would like to link against. It is general I suppose.

Comment: ***May I export to a txt?*** Try `dumpbin /EXPORTS libname.lib > dump.txt` Then open the text file with your favorite text editor.

Comment: @drescherjm Well, thanks, it will be useful. I have found the named function in the list, it says it is external. The library is linked against the project but it still gives an lnk2019 error.

Comment: I'm generally developing on UNIXes so I'm not sure if it is applicable: on UNIX when linking the order of library _does_ matter: it is necessary to provide libraries using symbols from other libraries before the libraries providing them. I vaguely recall that I had similar issues when using MSVC++ but I'm using MSVC++ too rarely to tell for sure.

Comment: @DietmarKühl Thanks for the advice, that was what I was afraid of, then I have to write an inheritance graph and probably it will help.

Comment: @DietmarKühl It seems it didn't help though.

Comment: 3Ducker: as I said, I'm normally not using MSVC++. It is something I observe frequently on UNIXes. The tools I'm using on UNIX to debug these problems also won't help on Windows...

Comment: @DietmarKühl I see, but it could have been a problem anyway. But either way, thanks for your idea.

Comment: The link order does not matter with MSVC.